# Записать значение переменной в другой файл

Tags: php

Есть файл `test.txt`, в нем текст `"$hello,просто текст"`. Получаю текст из файла через:

```
$get = file_get_contents("test.txt");
$hello = "123";
```

И хочу записать текст в другой файл, например в `test2.txt`, но уже с текстом `"123, просто текст"`, т.е необходимо просто взять значение из переменной, `а` `"просто текст"` оставить неизменным.
Как только уже не пробовал, всегда записывает `"$hello, просто текст"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заменяем `$hello` в строке на `123` и пишем.

```
$hello = str_replace('$hello', '123', $hello);
file_put_contents('test2.txt', $hello);
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @SoulEngine, пожалуйста.